# Decoupling a UI implementation from a class request

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

We have a situation where there are a series of steps that need to run, but the order/quantity of steps can change at runtime. Also, other programmers can create new steps that inherit from an abstract base we've defined. These are basically `tasks` so they take a certain amount of time to execute.

This is all well and good and our handling has been nicely abstracted from a UI point of view - we can treat each step as it's base class and build up our UI code without needing to know the implementation details inside each step.

However, we've run into a problem when certain steps require user interaction. For example, a step needs a user to hit a 'confirm' button before proceeding. We'd like to solve this in a way that's flexible and not tightly coupled both since the steps might change at runtime and to accommodate different UIs. One application might use a dialog box, another might use a button on the mainwindow, and a commandline app might require a keyboard press (for example). To make things a little harder, sometimes a step might require a value to be passed back. For example it makes a request and waits to receive a numeric back to use in it's work. In this case I imagine it passing a prompt and receiving back a numeric and this would be a generic enough implementation that different classes that needed a numeric back would use trigger the same UI code.

Summary:

1. Derived classes can trigger a UI element
2. Class can receive data back from user via the UI
3. Class definition or code determines whether and which type of UI element is shown
4. UI code determines implementation of displaying and returning values

This is probably a problem that's been solved, I'm just not sure what exactly I should be reading more about or searching for.

---

**Example and possible solutions**
I think I was being a little too abstract in my initial question.

For this example we are implementing code that bakes cookies. So we have a base class (*task*) called **Step**. In order to make the cookies we need to run several steps (add ingredient, mix, bake, cool). All of these take non-zero time but can be treated identically from the UI/XAML.

That is until the developer programming the Bake step requires input from the user to specify a temperature (for example). He could just code a dialog box into his step, but this is ugly and breaks our clean separation. He could tell the UI developer an event or property to bind to, but this is not at all dynamic.

Potential solutions:

1. Have an intermediate class (Notification Manager) that accepts requests from the step and makes them available to the UI. This seems like a lot of plumbing, especially when returning a value is required.
2. Events or WeakEvents - without a lot of code that's similar to #1 events are too strictly defined. WeakEvents look promising, but aren't a perfect fit either.

There has to be a design pattern, class, or extension that takes care of this. It's more a matter of not knowing what I'm looking for.

Comment: Each step actually makes use of the TPL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl). The question isn't how to handle parallel tasks, that's solved. It's more around having a task trigger a UI element without having to set bindings at compile time.

Comment: Use implicit DataTemplates or a DataTemplateSelector to display different subclasses differently. “Trigger a UI element” doesn’t signify anything to me in WPF terms; can you share code for that?

Comment: So you need some class design guidelines?